# when first tab is active, second doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tabs

I have a couple tabs in my page, The first tab is default but second should be open if some some data is wrong. I've been tried to set default tab thru expression but, if expression is working and the second tab is open, click on the first tab doesn't work, What I'm doing wrong?

```
 <uib-tab heading="First Tab" active ="true">
     <div>blah blah blah  content...</div> 
 </uib-tab>

 <uib-tab heading="Second Tab" active ="!(getSectionData.isGood)">
     <div>blah blah blah content 2...</div>
 </uib-tab>

</uib-tabset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <uib-tab heading="First Tab" active ="getSectionData.isGood">
     <div>blah blah blah  content...</div> 
 </uib-tab>

 <uib-tab heading="Second Tab" active ="!getSectionData.isGood">
     <div>blah blah blah content 2...</div>
 </uib-tab>

</uib-tabset>
```

Use your existing variables. When getSectionData.isGood is true the default one will be shown and when getSectionData.isGood is false the other own will be shown.

Just remember to set `getSectionData.isGood = true;` early on and when you want to show the other tab set `getSectionData.isGood = false;`. It will flip round which one is active.

Also you do not need () around expressions. If you want to evaluate and expression you might have to do `{{getSectionData.isGood}}`. Which mean the attribute will see `active="true"` instead of `active="getSectionData.isGood"`.

Comment: now i've got an error                                                                                 Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '!getSectionData.isGood' used with directive 'uibTab' is non-assignable!

Comment: yeah you was right, I define a couple variables and made them equal to my function so now everything works fine, thank you very much!